# Autoupdate file on edit in PhpStorm

Tags: tfs, version-control, phpstorm

Is there a way in PhpStorm to enable auto update from VCS (in my case I'm using TFS) on file editing?

Actually if I edit a file that was changed, PhpStorm automatically checkout the file but before doesn't retrieve latest version, so I edit a different copy of the file and it warns me that it's an old copy only when I'm proceeding to checking in of the file...

Comment: It looks like autoupdate isn't available out of the box (especially for tfs). There's a git plugin though that provides auto-fetch: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7499-gittoolbox

Comment: But it cannot be applicated to TFS I think, right?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Do you use Git or TFVC?

Comment: I'm using TFVC, the TFS version is 2013

Comment: yeah, looks like this can't be applied to TFVC

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, there isn't a good way to auto update from VCS.

The update command can only be triggered from the context menu. Please see [Update Directory / Update File Dialog (CVS)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/update-directory-update-file-dialog-cvs.html)

I can think of is that you can record a script for the update actions within the PhpStorm (`VCS --> TFS --> Update Directory...`), then run the script with the scheduled task in windows to update the project periodically.

[image]